# Blending previous frame when rendering in WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, canvas, webgl

Using a regular 2d canvas it is possible to get some cool effects by filling the entire canvas with a transparent version of the background color while drawing other graphics. Something like:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"; 
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

How would one get a similar ghosting/blending effect using WebGL?

I tried setting glClearColor with a transparent value, but this didn't work. Perhaps it can be done with blendFunc? If so, what arguments would I pass to blendFunc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is rendering to texture and displaying it on the screen on a full-screen quad.

Look at [Lesson 16 at learningwebgl](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786) and at [Section 9.090 of OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0090) (note the orthogonal view). Target texture may be as big as your viewport, but then you have to [follow the rules for NPOT textures](http://khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support).

To achieve really good looking effects you would probably need two custom framebuffers. Detailed explanation may be found in [Chapter 21 of GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html) (online).

Answer (score 1):

glClearColor with a transparent value did not work for me too. But repeatedly drawing a transparent rectangle covering the entire output area with blending enabled brought out the effect you were looking for in some cases. I used
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). Please look at http://db.tt/6QpXqzx for a simple example. The code is available on 'View Page Source'.
The code is structured as in the tutorials at the learningwebgl site.